# Ansible can't find the drive

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I am trying to do a simple task using the `win_copy` module which has to run through AWX. The task copies one file from drive `C:` to drive `F:`. But I am facing the following error:

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": "F:\test\", "msg": "Unhandled exception while executing module: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'F' does not exist.", "src": "C:\ansible-scripts\lol.txt"}

I am pretty sure that my playbook is correct because if I change a destination folder to somewhere in drive `C:` it is working. Even creating a powershell script which will do the same does not work with the same error. Also a noticed that if you change the drive while running the `win_command` module like this:

```yaml
win_command: test.bat
args:
  chdir: D:\whatever-folder
```

It will fail with the same error. Am I missing something? Could someone help me with these please?

Comment: How are the `D:` and `F:` drives mounted and where do they point to ? Network and user specific drives mounted at session start might not be available when running through a winrm connection.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the hint. I have looked at those drives in disk management and found out that they are not available due to the fact that they are substed. Resubsting the drive helped.